# Count friend's posts on Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I need to count how many posts my friends has of a given period.
Is that possible to count status updates from friends through Facebook API?

Answer (score 0):

You can just query the graph api on https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/posts

which will return an array with all the relevant info on each post.  That should be enough to get you started at least.

Try the graph explorer here...
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts

Comment: Actually I need to count how many statuses updates every friend had done in a period.

To each friend request count is taking around 300ms, probably I need to find another way around this.

Comment: Well you can use groups and iterate through each member, etc, but yeah, slow.  Check on this link for some tips on increasing performance https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/627/

Comment: Trying to run a FQL, but no results:

`SELECT uid1, time, message
FROM status 
WHERE IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

Comment: I think maybe the "WHERE IN " needs to be something like "Where uid1  IN"  ??

Comment: All permission are ok, but no data is retrived:
`SELECT uid, status_id, time, message 
FROM status
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`